# How To Change default upload size in Asp.net 5 (MVC 6)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I want change default file size in asp.net 5 (MVC 6).

In MVC 5, For change it, I Use Web.config and bellow Command:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="209715200" targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

and

```
<requestLimits  maxAllowedContentLength="209715200" />
```

How I can change maxAllowedContentLength in Asp.net 5 (MVC6 rc1)?

Answer (score 0):

If you use IIS then you can do this by adding your own web.config in the wwwroot folder.

It should be to do this by code, but can't find anything else then this user confirmation that is coming. http://forums.asp.net/t/2023967.aspx?vNext%20maxRequestLength